# How to parse Json object that have a single array (Volley)

Tags: android, json, android-volley

here is the picture describe what I need
[image]

```
JSONObject flightStatuses = response.getJSONObject("flightStatuses");
```

can you tell me what I do after that?

Comment: **Welcome to Stack Overflow**, StackOverflow is neither a forum, tutorial site nor web search replacement. We can [**help with certain problems**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), but it's your job to [**put some efforts**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) in the first place, including elementary [**(re)search**](https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=KlC2WdDPCKzT8gfFz72QDw). Read [**how to ask perfect question**](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below code

```
JSONArray flightStatuses = response.getJSONArray("flightStatuses");

 JSONObject object = flightStatuses.getJSONObject(0);
```